# Problem: I keep getting an error in the browser when the second page of my project is submitted

Tags: php, browser, localhost

I've create a project in PHP for my class and it is to replicate the google signup pages and when the information are correctly entered it writes the user's info in a file called "users.txt". Here is the github link to the source files : https://github.com/Ryan30012/myProject

The first page is the index page, everything works great, but to submit the information you have to click the next button two times. Then comes the page with the error which is the "process.php". If you leave everything empty and you click on submit button it should output an error about some empty field, but instead nothing happens because there is a warning that appeared in the browser console which is this:
[image]
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured what was the problem. It what in condition of the form:
The variable $error was not define so I've just added the line:

```
$error = true;
```

After declaring all the other variables. Now everything works.